# Advance usage of UIStackViews

Tags: uiview, storyboard, xib, uistackview

I want to achieve this [image: design] using UIStackView
I know this is possible using the conditional code/conditional constraints in the .swift file by activating and deactivating some constraints.

**How can I achieve this using UIStackViews?**

Below are the results I want to achieve.

```
1) Space must be constant between small gray dots i.e. spacing value 12 
2) Size of the small dot is fixed i.e. width=5 for small dots and also fixed for the circle with text. 
3) I want to show #n(e.g. 6) dots for the iPhone6 between two big circles. Dots must be more or less based on the screen size.
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

[image]

1. StackView with 5 views : alignment = fill, distribution = fill
2. Views 1,3,5 (gray views) - view with custom width for the circle with text
3. Views 2 and 4 - equal width
4. Views 2 - stackview with 6 views for dots : alignment = fill, distribution = equal spacing

Please let me know IF any additional information is required.